# how to loop one dataframe to another dataframe and get the single matching record in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Dataframe 1 **

```
 +----+------+------+-----+-----+
 |key  |dc_count|dc_day_count   |
 +----+------+------+-----+-----+
 | 123 |13      |66             |
 | 123 |13      |12             |
 +----+------+------+-----+-----+
```

**rule Dataframe **

```
 +----+------+------+-----+-----++------+-----+-----+
 |key  |rule_dc_count|rule_day_count   |rule_out    | 
 +----+------+------+-----+-----++------+-----+-----+
 | 123 |2            |30               |139         |
 | 123 |null         |null             |64          |
 | 124 |2            |30               |139         |
 | 124 |null         |null             |64          |
 +----+------+------+-----+-----+----+------+-----+--
```

if dc_count>rule_dc_count and  dc_day_count > rule_day_count
populate corresponding rule_out
else
other rule_out"

**expected output**

```
 +----+------+------+-
 |key  |rule_out    | 
 +----+------+------+
 | 123 | 139        |
 | 124 |  64        |
 +----+------+------+
```

Comment: I think your expected out is wrong .. you will get this  ``` | 124 |  139 |  ``` not this  ``` | 124 |  64   | ```

Comment: I can't understand - else other rule_out ... can you elaborate on this

Comment: Each key I am having 2 rules. If one condition is matched then I have to populate the corresponding rule-out value. Otherwise need to populate null value of rule_dc_count and rule_day_count . Here key 123 satisfied the if condition that’s why need to populate value 139. Key 124 data is not satisfied the if condition so need to populate null value of count row value 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PySpark Version**

The challenge here to get the second row's value for a key in a same column, In order to resolve this LEAD() analytical function can be used.

**Create the DataFrame here**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(123,13,66),(124,13,12)],[ "key","dc_count","dc_day_count"])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(123,2,30,139),(123,0,0,64),(124,2,30,139),(124,0,0,64)],
                            ["key","rule_dc_count","rule_day_count","rule_out"])
```

**Logic to get the Desired Result**

```
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
_w = W.partitionBy('key').orderBy(F.col('key').desc())
df1 = df1.withColumn('rn', F.lead('rule_out').over(_w))
df1 = df1.join(df,'key','left')
df1 = df1.withColumn('condition_col', 
                     F.when(
  (F.col('dc_count') > F.col('rule_dc_count')) & 
  (F.col('dc_day_count') > F.col('rule_day_count')),F.col('rule_out'))
                     .otherwise(F.col('rn')))

df1 = df1.filter(F.col('rn').isNotNull())
```

**Output**

```
df1.show()
+---+-------------+--------------+--------+---+--------+------------+-------------+
|key|rule_dc_count|rule_day_count|rule_out| rn|dc_count|dc_day_count|condition_col|
+---+-------------+--------------+--------+---+--------+------------+-------------+
|124|            2|            30|     139| 64|      13|          12|           64|
|123|            2|            30|     139| 64|      13|          66|          139|
+---+-------------+--------------+--------+---+--------+------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming expected output as-

```scala
+---+--------+
|key|rule_out|
+---+--------+
|123|139     |
+---+--------+
```

Below query should work-

```scala
spark.sql(
      """
        |SELECT
        | t1.key, t2.rule_out
        |FROM table1 t1 join table2 t2 on t1.key=t2.key and
        |t1.dc_count > t2.rule_dc_count and t1.dc_day_count > t2.rule_day_count
      """.stripMargin)
      .show(false)
```